# File size is zero when using curl to download a file

Tags: php, file, curl, permissions

the code im using to download the file is below

```
<?PHP
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://10.10.135.196/test.mp3';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$st = curl_exec($ch);
$fd = fopen('/home/user/Desktop/music/test.mp3', 'w+');
fwrite($fd, $st);
fclose($fd);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

on execution the file in the directory is show below is created, where the file size is zero

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data       0 2013-06-12 13:49 test.mp3
```

the music folder permission are shown below

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data root       4096 2013-06-12 15:42 music
```

**So here is the question, why is it not writing anything to the test.mp3 file?**

note: i also tried to use the below options, with the same result;

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fd); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: Did you check that $st is actaully contains data? I would verify that your curl is actually connecting and grabbing the contents of the file. You could also simplify your file write using file_put_contents($filename, $content).

Comment: it seems that $st did not have any data (forgot that i should check it), restarted apache, and now it works like a charm...... :)

Comment: You can do it somewhat more effectively with `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FILE,$fd);` b.t.w. But that's just nitpicking ;)